# ¿Es posible agrega algún código que traiga el año en curso dentro de la dirección del href?

Tags: html, href

por ejemplo tengo una lista como esta(entre otras muchas mas):

```
`<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="menu/histórico/2021/MarioSabedra"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="menu/histórico/2021/FelipeAlberto"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="menu/histórico/2021/JuanTorres"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="menu/histórico/2021/MariaAraya"></a>
    </li>
</ul>`
```

pero el año '2021' se tiene que cambiar a '2022'(el año en curso) y esto siempre se a echo desde hace tiempo por lo que quisiera que esto se realizara automáticamente por eso pregunto si es que ay algún código para colocar el año en curso a cada link del listado, aclaro que soy nuevo en programación y e estado buscando por algunas paginas pero solo e encontrado cosas como `a href="{% url 'index' %}"></a>` o `<a href="mailto:algien@gmail.com"></a>`.

Comment: Si es html puro (sin PHP o algo que la genere detrás) entonces no te queda otra que seguir haciendolo a mano. Se podria intentar con javascript, pero no seria interpretado siempre por los buscadores y perderias SEO (si es que eso es importante para esas páginas o para ti). Otra opcion, si son archivos HTML puros, como decia, seria pasarles instrucciones desde la linea de comandos que reemplazaran esas cadenas de texto en los archivos, es decir, que buscaran /2021/ y lo cambiaran por /2022/, eso tambien seria factible y no tendrias que editarlos uno a uno, pero serian cambios globales.

Comment: gracias por la pronta respuesta, claro tienes razón eso seria lo mas rápido asta el momento de igual manera seguiré buscando, muchas gracias